# Trying to fix a element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to fix a position when the document is ready. I started to do the code below but there is no change. What could I be possibly doing wrong? (I'm a JS/Jquery newbie, so the answer could be all...).

Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    document.getElementById('teste').style.display.position ="fixed";
});
```

Comment: Why do you use jquery to get the "ready" event and then use vanilla js to set the style? try $("#teste").css({position: "fixed"});

Comment: Reverted question because the "new requirements" form a completely different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.display`. That is a separate CSS property that has nothing to do with what you want to achieve.

Comment: By removing that it helps. (Updated the post because of new requirements...)

Comment: @DinisFigueira — You seem to have updated the post to turn it into a completely different question. If you have a new question, then accept an answer to the old one, then [ask a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (but your question appears to be "How do I put JavaScript in another file?" which you should be able to answer with about 60 seconds work with Google).

Answer (score 0):

Like so?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#teste").css("position","fixed");
})
```

Comment: That works too (Updated the post because of new requirements...)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply in `CSS` without `jQuery` like

```
#teste{
    position : fixed;
}
```

Using jQuery

```
$("#teste").css("position","fixed");
```

Comment: But it was simply to test since I'm going to need it in javascript to fix an element when scrolling..